# Game with 2020! consecutive integers, each turn select a and b, then write a new number on the board, which is a + b − ab/100

Tags: contest-math, game-theory

> On the board, there are 2020! consecutive integers, from 1 to 2020!. Kevin plays the following
>   game: Each turn, he erases two random numbers, assume that they are a and b, then he writes a new number
>   on the board, which is a + b −
>   ab/100 . After 2020! − 1 turns, there is one number left on the board. Does that
>   number depend on what number Kevin erases?(If not, what is that number?(Prove it.)If yes, prove it.)

I don't know how to approach this problem.
This problem comes from COFFEE contest problem 4 (it already ended).

Comment: I would try playing the game for $3!$ numbers and look for a result you can generalize to n! numbers.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  I ask because the $2020$ suggests a contest, and there is a site policy against answering questions about ongoing contests.

Comment: Just how immortal is this Kevin and just how dull does he find existence on this physical plane to be?

Answer (score 5):

Solution 1:

Just note that, if one of $a$ and $b$ is $100$, then the number $a + b - ab/100$ remains $100$.

In other words, the number $100$ "eats" any other number.

Thus in whatever order he erases and writes numbers, in the end the number $100$ will eat all other numbers and thus the final number must be $100$.

---

Solution 2:

As a more general approach, for every number $x$, let $f(x)$ denote $1 - x / 100$.

It is then easy to see that $f(a)f(b) = f(a + b - ab/100)$.

This means that however he erases and writes numbers, the product of $f(x)$ for all numbers $x$ on the board does not change.

Since there is originally $100$ on the board, and $f(100)$ is zero, the final number $x$ must also satisfy $f(x) = 0$ and hence $x = 100$.

Comment: +1 Nice. What's the thought process to coming up with $f(x)$?

Comment: @CalvinLin It's hard to explain. It probably comes from experience, since I have encountered many similar problems before.

Comment: Yea, same here. This was one of the harder ones to motivate. I  came up with $ \ln ( 1 - \frac{x}{100} ) $ because I was using the standard approach of summing up the invariance.